# .Off() on specific element when event bound to whole document

Tags: jquery, listener, preventdefault, eventtrigger

I have an event, lets just call it a click event that is triggered whenever a certain element `.clickable` is clicked. This element can be found multiple times anywhere in the document and is listened to with an `.on('click')` bound to the document like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickable", function(){
    alert("element clicked");
});
```

**For the sake of this question lets assume I can't change this, that click listener must be bound to the document level with the scope of just .clickable elements.**

Now sometimes this page will have one of these clickable elements nested inside an area where we need this click event to **not** do the default alert action, but do something else instead. Since this piece of code has to come after the previous listener, scoped to the document level, no preventative functions such as `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropogation()` stop the default action, as this code is fired after the other.

I though I could do something like:

```
$(document).off("click", ".nonDefaultActionArea .clickable");
$(document).on("click", ".nonDefaultActionArea .clickable", function(){
    alert("alternative action taken");
});
```

Which I though would unbind any clicks coming from that area to stop the default action and rebind it to new action. This however doesn't work as the first click listener isnt bound to `.nonDefaultActionArea .clickable` it is bound to `document`.

**So I ask:** Is there anyway, given the stipulation that I cannot change the first listener, and whatever code I introduce must come after the first listener; can I prevent the first action and trigger the alternative action.

JsFiddle depicting issue: https://jsfiddle.net/y7kumqh2/

Comment: No, if you can't use `stopPropagation`, and can't unbind the event handler from the document with `off()`, there's no *good* way to do this. Also,FYI, event handlers bound with `on()` must be removed from the elements they where actually bound on, not the delegated target. If you can, you can add someting to the elements that aren't supposed to fire the event handler, like a data-attribute, and then check for that in the event handler bound to the document, or just check in the event handler if the elements are inside the given area etc.

Comment: Here's an example -> https://jsfiddle.net/y7kumqh2/1/